# Ubuntu failed to start while booting

Tags: 22.04

When OS is working

I tried to take ownership of the filesystem in which Ubuntu is installed to give write permissions in filesystem

Then when Ubuntu is restarted this error appears.

[image]

Comment: "*I tried to take ownership of the filesystem*" Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1486244/edit) to clearly show us the exact command(s) you ran.

Comment: The ACPI error is expected, it has nothing to do with your problem. If I have to guess your file system is corrupt. Try starting in recovery mode and run a file system check. Then run the package repair utility.

Comment: Tried but it's same

Comment: "I tried to take ownership of the filesystem" - If your attempt involved `sudo`, `chown -R` or `chmod -R`, you have broken your system. Reinstall. Read `man sudo sudoers mount fstab` when you have a working system.

Comment: I have tried it from the disk to take ownership

Comment: In all honesty, it’s completely unclear what you did to end up in this state. Can you please - as the comments recommend - say _exactly_ what you did to get to this point? ‘I tried to take ownership…’ doesn’t tell us enough. Thank you.

Comment: 1. When I'm trying to move something in my filesystem it's saying you don't have write permission, then I tried to take ownership of the filesystem using disk. 2. Then I tried to restart my system and started receiving this error

Comment: @Harsh Gupta Elaborate on *exactly* what you did to "take ownership of the file system".  What did you do "using disk", and/or what *exact* commands you ran

Answer (score 0):

> When I'm trying to move something in my filesystem it's saying you don't have write permission

In most cases, you are not supposed to touch system files. Only move files around the file system if you know what you are doing.

In such case, the appropriate way to move the file is to run the command as super user,

```
sudo mv /source/file/location /destination/file/location
```

**Warning**: Moving important system files to different location may ruin your installation, and you may have to reinstall.

---

> I tried to take ownership of the filesystem

Taking the ownership will destroy Ubuntu. **Now you will have to reinstall.**
In case you have important files saved in your home folder/root partition, use the live USB to back them up to other partitions/external devices before you reinstall Ubuntu.

Comment: I have reinstalled Ubuntu, but is there any way to take ownership?

Comment: No. Don't try that. If you need to change a system files, use sudo. Ubuntu is not windows. Users are not supposed to edit system files

Comment: Why do you want to take ownership? Which system file do you want to change